How can I make Microsoft.Playwright run on azure app service?
The issue lies on calling the Playwright.CreateAsync() method, this just keeps on loading forever. My initial assessment is because playwright wants to access the browser but it cannot, that's why it's just keep on loading. I already called the install api of playwright.
Microsoft.Playwright.Program.Main(new[] { "install", "chromium" });

or
Microsoft.Playwright.Program.Main(new[] { "install"});

It was just because this method that the next line of code are not executed.
 using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();

Here's the entire code
 //_logger.LogInformation("Playwright installing.");
 Microsoft.Playwright.Program.Main(new[] { "install", "chromium" });
 //_logger.LogInformation("Playwright installed.");

 _logger.LogInformation("Playwright launching browser.");
 using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
 await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
 {
     Headless = true,
 });
 _logger.LogInformation("Playwright browser launched.");

 await using var context = await browser.NewContextAsync();
 var page = await context.NewPageAsync();
 await page.SetContentAsync(HTMLString);

 // Generate the PDF
 var output = await page.PdfAsync(new PagePdfOptions
 {
     Format = "A4", // or "letter"
     Landscape = false,
     HeaderTemplate = headerTemplate,
     FooterTemplate = footerTemplate,
     DisplayHeaderFooter = true,
     Margin = new Margin { Top = "0.5in", Bottom = "0.5in", Left = "0.5in", Right = "0.5in" },
 });

 return output.ToArray();

Additional info I found is that, in my local machine the browser binaries is located on C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\ms-playwright and this path does not exist on the server.

are you using the azure app service  of function app(or) web app ?

I'm using web app.

Can you share your code in git link

I decided to stop using playwright since it doesn't have a workaround on azure(Which I believe). I replace it with IronPDF for much simpler solution. Thank you.

In azure to run microsoft-playwright-run on-azure-app-service we need change the path to below
 "PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH", "value": "/home/site/wwwroot/.playwright/ms-playwright"



_logger.LogInformation("Playwright installing.");
Microsoft.Playwright.Program.Main(new[] { "install", "chromium" });
_logger.LogInformation("Playwright installed.");

_logger.LogInformation("Playwright launching browser.");
// Set PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH to the correct location
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH", $"{context.FunctionAppDirectory}\\bin\\");

// Create Playwright instance
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();

// Launch browser
await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
});
_logger.LogInformation("Playwright browser launched.");

// Create a new browser context and page
await using var browserContext = await browser.NewContextAsync();
var page = await browserContext.NewPageAsync();

// Set HTML content
string HTMLString = "<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>";
await page.SetContentAsync(HTMLString);

// Generate the PDF
var output = await page.PdfAsync(new PagePdfOptions
{
    Format = "A4",
    Landscape = false,
    DisplayHeaderFooter = true,
    Margin = new Margin { Top = "0.5in", Bottom = "0.5in", Left = "0.5in", Right = "0.5in" },
});



If you are utilizing an Azure function, you should follow this link for guidance on managing browser binaries with Playwright.

using IronPdf from this reference git
using IronPdf;
using IronSoftware.IronPdfConsoleDotNetCoreSamples.Infrastructure;

namespace IronSoftware.IronPdfConsoleFrameworkSamples
{
    public class DigitalSignatures : IExecuteApp
    {
        public string OutputPath { get ; set; }

        public void Run()
        {
            // Install IronPdf with Nuget:  PM> Install-Package IronPdf
      
            //The quickest way to cryptographically sign an existing PDF a digital certificate
            //new IronPdf.PdfSignature("Iron.p12", "123456").SignPdfFile("any.pdf");

            // All done in 1 line of code!
            //Advanced example for more control
            // Step 1. Create a PDF
            IronPdf.HtmlToPdf Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
            PdfDocument doc = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>Testing 2048 bit digital security</h1>");
            // Step 2. Create a Signature.
            // You may create a .pfx or .p12 PDF signing certificate using Adobe Acrobat Reader. 
            // Read: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/digital-ids.html
           // var signature = new IronPdf.PdfSignature(@"Inputs\cert123.pfx", "123");
            // Step 3. Optional signing options and a handwritten signature graphic
           // signature.SigningContact = "support@ironsoftware.com";
           // signature.SigningLocation = "Chicago, USA";
           // signature.SigningReason = "To show how to sign a PDF";
            //signature.LoadSignatureImageFromFile(@"Inputs\logo.png");
            //Step 4. Sign the PDF with the PdfSignature. Multiple signing certificates may be used
           // doc.SignPdfWithDigitalSignature(signature);
            //Step 4. The PDF is not signed until saved to file, steam or byte array.
            doc.SaveAs($@"{OutputPath}\DigitalSignatures.pdf");
        }
    }
}


